# Matching arxiv regular expression in Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have paragraph and from it I want to extract the arxiv dois. For example, this is the given paragraph:

```
"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.

Further information can be referred to this [arXiv article]`(https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.05857).`"
```

The output should be: `https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.05857`.
The start of arxiv doi will always be "https://arxiv.org" or "arxiv.org" and the appeded string could be anything.

I tried `exp = re.findall("^https://arxiv.org*", str)` but it doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciating.

Comment: Do not use built-ins as variable names in Python. Also, what is the rule here? Extract `https://arxiv.org` links from inside parentheses? Then just use `re.findall(r"\(((?:https?://)?arxiv\.org[^()]*)\)", text)`

Comment: No, extracting from parentheses is not a rule. It could be in parentheses and it couldn't be.

Comment: Then what is the stop criterion/a?

Comment: May be . or ) or end of line

Comment: No, there are `.`s in the URL, you can't use `.` as a stop criterion.

Comment: Try `re.findall(r"\b(?:https?://)?arxiv\.org\S*\b", text)`

Comment: I got your point. I think first answer is good second regular expression is picking the text if  something is written after that. So I'll go for the first solution and thank you very much :)

Comment: But maybe the stop criteria can be where the digits are ending. For example, in this string (https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.05857), after 7 there is not a digit we may be we can stop it there but still the `.` can create an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

string = """Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
Further information can be referred to this [arXiv article]`(https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.05857).`"""

pattern=re.compile('\((https://arxiv.org[^\)]+|arxiv.org[^\)]+)', re.MULTILINE)
pattern.findall(string)

#output
#['https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.05857']
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing, the "^" is wrong - as that would only match text at the begining of the line. The * after the g also does not mean "anything" - but "any number of g".

You could try with
re_res=re.findall("https://arxiv.org/[^\s\)\]]*[0-9]"

It is not fool proof but should cover most cases.

find `https://arxiv.org/`
that is followed by anything (`*`) not (`[^...]` space `\s` closing round or square brackets(`\)\]`) (together `[^\\s\\\)\\]]*`) but ends whith a number (`[0-9]`).